# Email notifications not working after backup and restore procedure

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I restore my gitlab CE in a new server (ubuntu), I just follow the step everything works fine until I notice that I didn't receive any email notification when someone create an issue, comment on my issue, etc... I already check my settings, almost all movements will notify me via email, but nothing happens.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue? I've been searching for days to find the solution, and no luck at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gitlab configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

Uncomment:

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'noreply@gitlab.example.com'
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'none'
```

Install [Postfix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/reply_by_email_postfix_setup.html) if you haven't:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

If you want send via SMTP server, configure other [SMTP settings](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md#gmail).

Restart Gitlab:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Check logs:

```
sudo less /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log
sudo gitlab-ctl tail
sudo less /var/log/mail.log
```

Comment: I scanned `mail.log` this is sample result: `connect to mx-ex2013.myodomain.com.ph[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25: Connection timed out`

Comment: Did you checked https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-can-t-send-email-externally-postfix or http://serverfault.com/questions/585503/postfix-connection-timed-out-on-all-outbound-email ?

Comment: yes and still error occurred. I just follow the restore process of gitlab and this happen. Before the backup email notification is working fine.

Comment: Do you use local or external SMTP server? Do you get connection timeout when 'telnet mailserver.example.com 25'?

Comment: I wasn't able to telnet my current smtp where the timeout occured, how to change my current smtp?

Comment: Did you modify /etc/postfix/master.cf as it is mentioned on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/i-can-t-send-email-externally-postfixv ?

Comment: I already tried that but no luck at all. I think i need a fresh install of gitlab.